# How to use for-loop (or apply) in R to filter and select specific columns with specific terms

Tags: r, for-loop, filter, lapply

I am trying to make a table like this -

[image: sample table]

The table contains several scenarios and risk_type.
The scenarios are basically filters. For example 
0 - loan_age > 18 
1 - interest_rate > 8% 
2 - interest_rate > 18% AND referee ==  "MALE" AND new_LTV > 50

risk_type are columns in the original dataset like

A - flood risk 
B - wildfire risk 
C - foundation risk

What I want to do is to create a summary table of all these different risks for all the filters.

This is how the data looks like -

[image: sample data]

Damage and new LTV is a function of risk score, and I want to filter for risk score > 4

Edit - The first 5 rows of the dummy dataframe.

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), LTV_value = c(43, 43, 32, 
34, 35), loan_age = c(17, 65, 32, 33, 221), referee = c("MALE", 
"FEMALE", "MALE", "MALE", "FEMALE"), interest_rate = c(0.02, 
0.03, 0.05, 0.0633333333333333, 0.0783333333333333), value = c(70000, 
80000, 90000, 1e+05, 45000), flood_risk_score = c(3, 4, 5, 0, 
1), wildfire_risk_score = c(3, 4, 3, 3, 2), foundation_risk_score = c(5, 
5, 2, 0, 1), flood_damage = c(21000, 32000, 45000, 0, 4500), 
    wildfire_damage = c(21000, 32000, 27000, 30000, 9000), foundation_damage = c(35000, 
    40000, 18000, 0, 4500), new_LTV_flood = c(40, 39, 27, 34, 
    34), new_LTV_wildfire = c(40, 39, 29, 31, 33), new_LTV_foundation = c(38, 
    38, 30, 34, 34)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Till now I have tried these methods.

```r
risk_list = c("flood_risk_score"
               , "wildfire_risk_score"
               , "foundation_risk_score")

for (i in risk_list){
table <- df %>% 
  filter(df[i] > 3) %>%
  summarise(Count = n()
            , mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)
            , LTV = mean(LTV)) 

# Using rbind() to append the output of one iteration to the dataframe
table_append= rbind(table_append, table)
}
```

This helps me get the values for all the risk scores, however, I have two issues here.

1. I am unable to filter according to a filter list

For the filter list, I tried this code, but I am unable to add it in a loop -

```r
filters_list = list(which(df$interest > 8)
                    , which(df$loan_age > 18))
```

2. For LTV update, all of them have different new LTV

All of them need to be filtered for high LTV using their new LTV scores

```r
risk_type_list = c("flood"
                   , "wildfire"
                   , "foundation")
for (i in list(paste0(risk_type_list,"_risk_level"))){
 table <- df %>% 
 filter(df[paste0(i,"_risk_level")] > 3) %>%
 summarise(Count = n())
 #Using rbind() to append the output of one iteration to the dataframe
 table_append = rbind(table_append, table)
}
```

In the end, I want to have code that will generate data from the given data by putting in required filters for all different risk types and also use their new LTV values.

Comment: Could you please share a few rows of your `df` data in valid R syntax? `dput(df[1:5, ])` will do that in a copy/pasteable format for the first 5 rows. We can't test code on a picture of data.

Comment: @GregorThomas I have added the dataset!